# Prove that for any k>0 the least upper bound of T={ka:a∈S} is kλ.

Tags: real-analysis

Let S⊆R be a non-empty set of reals that is bounded above, with a least upper bound λ. Prove that for any k>0 the least upper bound of T={ka:a∈S} is kλ.

I know that I need to show that kλ is an upper bound for T and that it's less than or equal to any upper bound for T but I don't know how writing that out would look, specifically the part where I show that kλ is the LEAST upper bound I have been having trouble knowing what to write when proving least upper bounds

Comment: Try assuming the contrary and getting a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

If t is a member of the set kS then there exist s in S such that t= ks.  Since $\lambda$ is an upper bound on S, $\lambda> s$ so that $k\lambda> ks= t$.  Thus, $k\lambda$ is an upper bound on kS.  Suppose p is an upper bound on kS.  Then p> t= ks so that p/k> s.  That is p/k is an upper bound on S so must be greater than or equal to the **least** upper bound: $p/k\ge \lambda$.  From that, $p\ge k\lambda$, showing that $k\lambda$ is the **least** upper bound on kS.